# Debugging (possibly) OpenCV related crash on Jetson TK1

Tags: linux, opencv, crash, embedded-linux, nvidia

What I am looking for: I need help debugging consistently happening system crashes on my Jetson TK1.

System: I am using a Jetson TK1 board from NVIDIA. Updated to 21.3.4 Grinch Kernel. All drivers installed, libopencv4tegra installed alongside ROS (using hacked deb packages to not overwrite openCV). Everything used to work perfectly in this exact setup.

When the crashes happen: I am running a VSLAM program, which uses a camera connected on the USB port. The program is making heavy use of OpenCV. The program used to run for over 1 month without problems in the current setup. Now, I am getting consistent system crashes which result in a total system freeze. When I am connected over ssh, I loose connection. When I connect a monitor to see what happens on the system while it crashes, I can see everything freeze. The USB port also seems to turn off, since not even USB mouse and keyboard work anymore post-crash. The Jetson stays on though.

Crash Logs: I have tried looking into the /var/log/ logs, but none of them show any messages for when the crash happens.

I have run memtester before. It didn't return any bad memory. While running and crashing, the memory onboard is used at about 60-75% (as shown by "top"). CPU usage is around 60%.

The weird thing is that this exact setup has been running just like this for over a month now.

I need to know: are there any other logs I could find information about the crash in? How could I find out if this is related to a hardware failure or whether there's a software issue?

Thanks

-Marc

Comment: what about GPU RAM and GPU usage on the tk1? Can this be tested?

Comment: maybe you can create your own logfile that helps you finding out where in your program the system freezes? If it is OpenCV related you have to ask yourself why it didn't freeze before... so if it is a software failure (beside not checking things like whether image was captured successfully) you must ask yourself why it didn't occur earlier and now occurs regularly. Maybe there is some integer overflow (shouldnt happen if you restart the program, except you use global information). My tip is a hardware failure, but that's pure speculation :D

Comment: So the interesting thing is that now I also have the Jetson crash upon loading Xorg. I will try to do a reflash onto the stock 21.4, reinstall, and then report back.

Comment: sounds like a defect of the TK1 graphic chip. Maybe have a look at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/751869/embedded-systems/jetson-tk1-temperature/  and at http://elinux.org/Jetson/Thermal